# ORA-00923 Error while executing the query

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm using the below query in order to see the output but I'm getting the below error message. Could you please help me on this please.

### Query:

```
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(pr.Asset, '(.+):.+@',1,1,'i',1) as pr.instancename ,
upper(REGEXP_SUBSTR(pr.Asset, '.+@(.+)s-',1,1,'i',1)) as pr.Servername,
Asset,asset_type,check_category,check_desc,custom_attributes,check_id,db_attributes,occurances,organization,result_status,risk
FROM table1 pr
left join table2 ser on pr.Servername = ser.server_component_name
```

### Output Error:

```
ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected
00923. 00000 -  "FROM keyword not found where expected"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 1 Column: 59
```

Can some one please help me.

Regards,

Bharath Vikas

Comment: Column aliases can't be qualified. E.g. change from `pr.instancename` to `pr_instancename`.

Comment: I've changed it but not able to join the pr_Servername to the other table.

Comment: You can't use column aliases in the ON clause anyway. Derived tables is the trick!

Comment: Or just use the expression in the ON of your JOIN

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a few things wrong.

- If you use an alias for a calculated value, then don't add the table alias to it. It's not a column from a table.
- You can't directly join a table to an alias of a calculated value.  But wrap it in a sub-query and you can use it.

**Example:**

```
SELECT *
FROM (
 select 
   REGEXP_SUBSTR(Asset, '(.+):.+@',1,1,'i',1) as InstanceName,
   upper(REGEXP_SUBSTR(Asset, '.+@(.+)s-',1,1,'i',1)) as ServerName,
   Asset, asset_type, check_category, check_desc,custom_attributes, 
   check_id, db_attributes, occurances, organization, result_status, 
   risk
 from table1
) pr
left join table2 ser on (pr.ServerName = ser.server_component_name);
```

*Disclaimer: Only tested in notepad*

Some simplified examples:

```
-- BAD : an alias using an alias
select UPPER(f.bar) as f.UberBar 
from Foo f

-- BAD : Foo doesn't have an UberBar column
select UPPER(bar) as UberBar 
from Foo 
where UberBar = 'BAR'

-- OK : wrapped in a subquery and using the alias in the outer query
select * from (
   select UPPER(bar) as UberBar 
   from Foo
) as Q 
where Q.UberBar = 'BAR'

-- OK : repeat the calculation of the value in the ON of the JOIN, or the WHERE clause
select UPPER(bar) as UberBar 
from Foo
where UPPER(bar) = 'BAR'
```

Comment: Thanks for the code, I've modified it as per the requirement and is working fine now..!!!!

Comment: Glad that it worked.  I.m.h.o. it's a pity that Oracle still doesn't allow the direct reuse of an alias. I've worked on a Teradata RDBMS before, and on that database a query like `select (bar + 1) as calc1, (calc1 + 1) as calc2 from Foo where calc2 > 3` would be allowed.